# About the cube of a positive integer

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have had yet another observation in number theory- The sum of the digits of every cube except those of the form 1,10,100,1000... is an even number. Prove or disprove.

Comment: What about $3^3=27$.

Comment: $3^3=27$ is a counterexample

Comment: It is true that the sum of the digits of cubes of numbers of the form $1,10,100,\dots$ are all odd (*$(10^k)^3=10^{3k}$ has only a single nonzero digit which is a one*) but as pointed it it is not true that these are the only such numbers.  They will however be the only such numbers whose digit sum is equal to exactly one (*performing the digit sum only once, not repeatedly as might be done in testing for divisibility by nine*).

Answer (score 1):

$$S(3^3)=S(27)=9$$

$$S(6^3)=S(216)=9$$

$$S(13^3)=S(2197)=19$$

etc.

Comment: I am sorry for that.

Comment: @user497826 No problem. Generally, when you have observations like this, it's a good idea to make a program to check the first $N$ values for some large $N$, and if it still holds and you can't figure out why then post it. For this one, it seems as if almost $1/2$ of positive cubes have an odd sum of digits.

Comment: Since I know absolutely no programming as a freshman what programming language and book would you recommend for math major

Comment: @user497826 I wouldn't call myself an authority on the subject, but I use Python for these sorts of things and it's pretty useful and easy-ish to learn. Another option is Mathematica if you can get it easily through your school; it has a lot of built-in mathematical functions that can be helpful. If you want to do more heavy-duty programming it's probably worth learning Java or a C-variant.

Comment: I am considering Python to be my choice. I have been thinking about it for a couple of weeks and am willing to self study John Guttag's book.